# Display the total weight of the order in the basket

Tags: views, commerce

I installed the module https://www.drupal.org/project/physical in my cart view, I'd see the total weight of the order. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add weight as a field to the product entity type first. Then you can see. Then you need to install [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc), make a view and calculate the total.

Hope that helps.